# Wobbly Windows in Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, 14.04, xubuntu, compiz

i tried to install compiz on Xubuntu 14.04 and changed the desktop to unity. as i open the compiz it shows "some features might not be available" and I am not able to see any option of Wobbly windows... kindly help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to get [CompizConfig Settings Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/), or `ccsm` for short. Then you need to install [Compiz-Plugins](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compiz-plugins/). Once you have those installed just open up CCSM and the wobbly windows options should be available.